# Sleep breaks the script

Tags: php

I want simply to set a sleep in a loop. But it doesn't work as expected

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    echo $i;
    sleep(1);
}
```

if the loop takes more than 5 seconds. It doesn't work (don't print at all).

I tested it in [Teh Playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/L53o5YVyf5rXO7JT), and this error appears :

> Execution took longer than 5 seconds, sent SIGTERM and terminated

Edit : Modifying set_time_limit doesn't change anything...

It seems it's related to my server's config...

Comment: Seems nothing wrong with your program, tehplayground.com terminates the program because its running for long time

Comment: thanks, it look like my server has also a timeout

Answer (score 1):

> **SIGTERM** is the signal that is typically used to administratively terminate a process and its triggered by tehplayground's some server settings which is not related to PHP

Because your program executes amount of time allowed on **tehplayground**, There is nothing wrong with your code.

I ran it on my server it works fine.

To increase the time limit on your server

For runtime

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 60); //60 secs
```

Change this on php.ini for permanent change

```
; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 300
```

Setting it to 0 means there's no time limit.

Comment: then i have to configurate my server

Comment: What do you want to configure? did you run the script on your local machine or server? it works perfectly fine to me

Comment: It's on a server

Comment: Do you want to increase the php execution time limit?

Comment: Glad to see that you found the issue

Comment: Yes, increasing time limit with set_time_limit doesn't change anything. I have to investigate about my server's configuration

Comment: `set_time_limit` is only for runtime, if you have set anything on hard settings on `php.ini` then set_time_limit will not any effect

Comment: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 10);` you can use this

Comment: Thanks, I have to try that (I have to ask the administrator of this server)

Comment: Great! happy coding

Comment: Please upvote and accept this as answer if this fixes your issue

Answer (score 0):

Set the second condition of `for` bigger, ie `$i <= 60;`

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 60; $i++) {
    echo $i;
    sleep(1);
}
```

The condition says "loop the block as many times as the $i is less than 6".
`for` is a function,

1. first you define value of $i equal to 1, `$i = 1;`
2. second you define the condition, ie do the block while $i is less then 6, `$i <= 6;`
3. third on each loop increase the $i by one (the double plus), `$i++`

Comment: please see the Teh Playground demo linked, it doesn't change anything

Comment: Nahouto as already commented Thamaraiselvam  - there is nothing wrong with your program, tehplayground.com terminates the program because its running for long time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your code, do you get any error on your own server?

I tried your code and it worked properly, just copy pasted it.

I think the error you're getting is just **TehPlayground** not liking something executing for more than 5 seconds because I set the for loop to less than 4 and didn't get the error message.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    echo $i;
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. On my server, if the total execution time exceeds 30 seconds, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This works fine when I ran it in my local machine. I think your script execution getting timed out at Teh Playground when it takes more than 5 seconds to execute.